# Trouble Copying Artifacts to Docker Container in Multi-Repository Setup

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying a new project where I have three pipelines across different repositories:

node-pipeline
maven-pipeline
A third pipeline in a separate repository that is responsible for downloading artifacts from the aforementioned pipelines.
My goal is to set up a Docker container utilizing the downloaded artifacts for both the Frontend and Backend. To achieve this, I've created a Dockerfile at the root of my repository. However, I'm encountering an issue where the Dockerfile is unable to fetch the files.

Here's the relevant portion of the Dockerfile:

`FROM ubuntu:latest WORKDIR /app ARG ARTIFACTS_DIR RUN echo "Artifacts Directory: ${ARTIFACTS_DIR}" COPY ${ARTIFACTS_DIR} /app RUN ls -l`

Upon execution, I receive the following error:
`#7 [4/5] COPY /home/vsts/work/1/a /app #7 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref 8fd12658-c561-4704-8f40-f8581cdb93b9::ksblzls4mg7rpnuui0qihh6tq: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount208492009/home/vsts/work/1: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount208492009/home/vsts/work/1: no such file or directory`

I've set up a Docker task in my CI/CD pipeline with the following configuration:
`- task: Docker@2 displayName: "Build an image " inputs: command: "build" dockerfile: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile" buildContext: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)" arguments: "--build-arg ARTIFACTS_DIR=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"`

Any insights into resolving this issue and successfully copying the artifacts to the container would be highly appreciated. In the end I want to create a container image that has both frontend and backend

I've tried passing $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) as an argument to the Dockerfile

I was expecting it to copy the files,It's only able to copy files that are available in the repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure that you have added [Publish Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-pipeline-artifact-v1?view=azure-pipelines) in "node-pipeline" and "maven-pipeline".
2. Because you've set the Docker Build Context to `Build.SourcesDirectory`, the COPY command will use it as the "current working directory." You need to download the artifacts to `Build.SourcesDirectory` using [Download Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v1?view=azure-pipelines) before consuming them in the Docker task.

Taking the following yaml as an example, it will download Artifacts "artifact1" and "artifact2" from two pipelines to the current pipeline's `Build.SourcesDirectory`.

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '{The project from which to download the pipeline artifact1}'
    definition: '{The build published the artifact1}'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '{The project from which to download the pipeline artifact2}'
    definition: '{The build published the artifact2}'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    tags: '$(tag)'
```

In the docker file, I copy all the content in `Build.SourcesDirectory` to /app.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN ls -l
```

Then I can see "artifact1" and "artifact2" when run `ls -l` in the log.
[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm, sorry for the late reply.